# Detect ONLY uBlock Origin adblocker (Vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, adblock

I'm using MoonPay for crypto purchasing in my Vue app, but uBlock Origin is blocking its IP address detection which blocks it from loading.

It doesn't seem to be an issue on other adblockers, so I'd like to display a message to the user if the user has uBlock Origin installed, however the issue doesn't seem to occur with other adblockers.

Is there a way to detect any one single adblocker, or a package which can return a string of the adblocker currently active?

Comment: If they have adblockers installed, that's on them. They already know how blocklists and exceptions work, so if a site doesn't load properly for them, let them do what they want to do about that.

Comment: Perhaps detect the failure in the JS and just report that that's the problem while suggesting it might be due to an ad-blocker?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Perhaps I could detect the failed fetch and display a modal only for that error event rather than relying on detecting the ad blocker. Great lateral thinking!

Comment: @TimTitus: Exactly. And it's not just assuming only one possible cause. Strict privacy protections in the browser to disable even safe cross-origin requests, or a network firewall blocking unclassified domains, or just their site being down (or the user's router crapping out after the page loads, before the request is dispatched, as happened to me a couple minutes ago) could all cause the same problem; the problem is that the user can't reach the site, it's not your job to guess *why*.

Comment: @ShadowRanger that solution worked perfectly! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @ShadowRanger suggested, I've solve this by catching the Axios error from the blocked third-party resource fetch and displaying a modal to the user to alert them to the problem.